# Extracting and replacing href tag using javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have no idea where to start with this so I was hoping someone might be able to suggest a solution.

How do I extract the contents of the href tag of "product_prev" (/images/New-Image.jpg) and use it to replace the href tag of "product" (/images/Old-Image.jpg)

Here is my HTML...

```
<a class="product_prev" href="/images/New-Image.jpg"><img alt="" title="" src="/images/New-Image.thumb.jpg" width="50"></a>

<a class="product" href="/images/Old-Image.jpg"><img class="displayer ct_pd_pi_mainImage ct_pd_pi_fullsizeImage" alt="" title="Venicci-Mini-Pram-Black" itemprop="image" src="/images/Old-Image.jpg"></a>
```

I'm unable to edit the template of the site but I can add CSS/Javascript/JQuery so hopefully a solution using these methods can be used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute selector of jquery to get and set the href

```
$(".product").attr("href",$("product_prev").attr("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with jQuery.

```
var first_href= $(".product_prev").attr('href');
$(".product").attr('href', first_href);
```